# Potential null pointer exception. The resource is missing in some of layout versions

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to develop an app and my onClick functions for my toggle buttons are not working. It says null pointer exception. The activity is not even opening. When i hover over my button name (coedb) in my code, it says "Potential null pointer exception. The resource is missing in some of layout versions"

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.savar.swoosh.leagueactivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/desiredleaguebg"
        android:contentDescription="@string/background_image" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.539"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/swooshlogo"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:text="@string/desired_league"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4">

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/manb"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/swoosh_toggle"
            android:onClick="menclick"
            android:text="@string/mens"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textOff="@string/mens"
            android:textOn="@string/mens" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/womenb"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/swoosh_toggle"
            android:onClick="woclick"
            android:text="@string/womens"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textOff="@string/womens"
            android:textOn="@string/womens" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/coedb"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/swoosh_toggle"
            android:text="@string/co_ed"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textOff="@string/co_ed"
            android:textOn="@string/co_ed" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nxt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/swooshbtn"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:onClick="next"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is a part of my code where the error is occuring:

```
class leagueactivity : baseactivity() {

    var choice = ""
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_leagueactivity)

        coedb.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this,"looollll",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
```

Here is my error:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                      Process: com.example.savar.swoosh, PID: 5402
                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.savar.swoosh/com.example.savar.swoosh.leagueactivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ToggleButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                          at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ToggleButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                          at com.example.savar.swoosh.leagueactivity.onCreate(leagueactivity.kt:17)
                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                          at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: two variants: you put your layout file into wrong res directory or in other res directory there is a layout file with same name, but it doesn't have your button

Answer (score 10):

This error occurs when you've created same layout for multiple `SDK INT` or orientation and not mentioned the view in all the layout files, say for: `activity_main.xml(v21)`or `activity_main(land)` and so on. All the layouts should contain all the views with same IDs

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is the correct syntax with kotlin, but your button variable is not initialized.
You should probably do something like:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_leagueactivity)

    coedb = findViewById(R.id.coedb)

    coedb.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(this,"looollll",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Kotlin automatically initializes the button using: " import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_leagueactivity.* ". It worked fine for a previous activity, but for this current activity its showing errors.

Comment: Are you sure you attached the correct xml (activity_leagueactivity.xml) to the question? It may just be missing R.id.coedb.

Comment: It is the last toggle button in my linear layout. "android:id="@+id/coedb" (if this is what you were referring to)

Comment: I was asking because you wrote it works for other activities and not for this one. So that made me think you might be using the wrong xml (or the xml you are using is missing this id).

Comment: I'm thinking it has something to do with the layout version. The id is working fine i guess. Because i customized the button looks to make it transparent with rounded borders. I'm thinking if that is what is causing the issue. (All of these things worked for my previous layout and are causing trouble in the current layout).

Comment: I just created an empty activity and copied everything from this activity to the new one and it worked. Not sure why this has occurred but.